# How to consume a web service hosted on https?

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap, https

I am trying to get data from a 3rd party soap web service which is hosted on https:// address and I keep getting the error {"The request failed with an empty response."}

I am trying it with the standard method "Add Service reference" > Advance > Web reference and the creating an instance and making call.

The service is accessible via web browser, I have tried working out with soapUI but it keeps giving error :

```
Error loading [https://serviceaddress.com/wa/ws/ver5/admin.asmx?wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: java.io.CharConversionException: Characters larger than 4 bytes are not supported: byte 0x92 implies a length of more than 4 byte
```

The Stack Message is as below:

```
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at com.certpointsystems.inforuat.VLSAdmin.FindCourses(String courseSearchInfo, String levelSearchInfo, String outputFilterXml, String& dataXml) in c:\Users\vsachdeva\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3027fa51\7bbbba28\App_WebReferences.ylr-phiq.0.cs:line 481
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\vsachdeva\Desktop\tempC#\WebSite1\Default.aspx.cs:line 24
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Please suggest a way to make if work.

Thanks in advance,
Vishal

Comment: Not enough info in your question to help much. The first thing to do is make sure that 3rd party service is available: try hitting service endpoint from a web browser, or better, the WSDL. Or use Fiddler to see what's happening on the wire.

Comment: @PeterB The service is accessible via browser.

Comment: you should update this with the code you are using to invoke the service. SOAPUI or Fiddler are great tools for testing, troubleshooting web services.